# OutOfMemory Exception for Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#

I have a console application which runs as 32 bit process(we cant change it to 64 bit) and is throwing Out of memory Exception. We traced minor Memory leak(related to Entity Framework repository) in a downstream process but with that too application should not cross 2 GB memory.
One thing i want to understand is sometimes application processes 2500 records while other times it fails at 100.(Server memory utilization is under 60% when this application is running
 I am using Parallel.forEach and controlling number of threads to 4 using ParallelOptions. Can anybody suggest making the application on a single thread may by any chance resolve the problem.
(The application didn't fail in any lower environment but only in production and giving us a very hard time).
Below is the code snippet.
Thanks In Advance,
Rohit

```
protected override void Execute(IEnumerable<PlanPremiumDetails> argument)
{
    if (argument.Any())
    {
        var EnrollmentRequests = argument.GroupBy(c => c.CaseNumber).ToList();
        SelectedPlanPremiumDetails request;
        EnrollmentResponse enrollmentResponse;

        bool taskStatus;
        Common.Status.TotalAutoEnrollRecords = EnrollmentRequests.Count;
        Common.StartTimer();
        Action<IGrouping<int,PlanPremiumDetails>> processRequest = eRequest =>
            {
                int caseNumber;
                List<EnrolledIndividual> enrolledIndividuals;
                try
                {

                    string errorMessage;
                    caseNumber = eRequest.Key;
                    if (eRequest.Any(f => f.FailedMCOEnrollmentId > 0))
                    {
                        request = FailedMcoRequest(eRequest, caseNumber);
                        enrollmentResponse = InvokeEnrollment(request);
                        if (enrollmentResponse.OverallStatus == false && enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA != null)
                        {
                            StringBuilder messages = new StringBuilder();
                            if (enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA.ErrorInformationPostMcaps != null)
                            {
                                messages.Append(enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA.ErrorInformationPostMcaps.Message);
                                Exception innerExp = enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA.ErrorInformationPostMcaps.InnerException;
                                if (innerExp  != null)
                                {
                                   // messages.Append(enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA.ErrorInformationPostMcaps.InnerException.Message);
                                    do
                                    {
                                        messages.Append(innerExp.Message);
                                        innerExp = innerExp.InnerException;
                                    }
                                    while (innerExp != null);
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA != null && enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA.InnerErrorInfo != null)
                                {
                                    foreach (var msg in enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA.InnerErrorInfo)
                                    {
                                        messages.Append( string.Format(@"ErrorCode: {0}, ErrorMessage: {1} ",msg.ErrorCode,msg.ErrorMessage));

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            errorMessage = Convert.ToString(messages);

                            Common.Errors.Add(new Exception(String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedEnrollErrorText"], caseNumber, errorMessage), enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA.ErrorInformationPostMcaps));
                            taskStatus = GenerateTask(eRequest, caseNumber, false, errorMessage);
                            if (taskStatus)
                            {
                                UpdateTriggerStatus(caseNumber, "Y");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                UpdateTriggerStatus(caseNumber, "N");
                                Common.Errors.Add(new Exception(String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedEnrollErrorText"], caseNumber, "Task Creation")));
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Common.Status.Success = (Common.Status.Success + 1);
                            UpdateTriggerStatus(caseNumber, "Y");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        enrolledIndividuals = eRequest.Select(p => new EnrolledIndividual
                        {
                            IndividualId = p.IndividualId,
                            EdgTraceId = p.EdgTraceId,
                            EDGNumber = p.EDGNumber
                        }).ToList();

                        request = new SelectedPlanPremiumDetails()
                        {
                            EmployerId = 0,
                            CaseNumber = caseNumber,
                            CallBackId = Common.ApplicationName,
                            SourceSystem = EnrollmentLibrary.SourceSystem.MAAUTOASSIGN,
                            AutoAssignMCOIndividuals = enrolledIndividuals
                        };
                        enrollmentResponse = InvokeEnrollment(request);
                        if (enrollmentResponse.OverallStatus == false && enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA != null)
                        {
                            StringBuilder messages = new StringBuilder();
                            if (enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA.ErrorInformationPostMcaps != null)
                            {
                                messages.Append(enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA.ErrorInformationPostMcaps.Message);
                                Exception innerExp = enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA.ErrorInformationPostMcaps.InnerException;
                                if (innerExp != null)
                                {
                                    // messages.Append(enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA.ErrorInformationPostMcaps.InnerException.Message);
                                    do
                                    {
                                        messages.Append(innerExp.Message);
                                        innerExp = innerExp.InnerException;
                                    }
                                    while (innerExp != null);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA != null && enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA.InnerErrorInfo.Count != null)
                                {
                                    foreach (var msg in enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA.InnerErrorInfo)
                                    {
                                        messages.Append(string.Format(@"ErrorCode: {0}, ErrorMessage: {1} ", msg.ErrorCode, msg.ErrorMessage));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            errorMessage = Convert.ToString(messages);

                            Common.Errors.Add(new Exception(String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AutoEnrollErrorText"], caseNumber, errorMessage), enrollmentResponse.ErrorInformationMA.ErrorInformationPostMcaps));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Update status to be saved in InterfaceSummary table.
                            Common.Status.Success = (Common.Status.Success + 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Common.Errors.Add(new Exception(String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AutoEnrollErrorText"], eRequest.Key, ex.Message), ex));
                }
            };
}




int dParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DegreeofParallelism"]);
        Parallel.ForEach(EnrollmentRequests,
            new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = dParallelism > 0 ? dParallelism : 1 },
            processRequest);
```

Comment: Get a memory profiler.

Comment: I'd suggest you the same, you need to profile this. The method is quite big and doing a lot of stuff. If you can't get a profiler, try to isolate the parallelism to minimum code, like the `InvokeEnrollment(request)` and implement callbacks to process this response. This may help tracking down the problem.

Comment: one big mistake i did is accessing app.config inside Action delegate. i modified above code to reflect that. can this exception occur if multiple threads try to access app.config at same time

Comment: What is the exception? And where does it fail, stacktrace will do...

Comment: its OutOfMemory Exception. Complete stacktrace as captured from event logis: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException
Stack:
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.EnsureCurrentThreadHasQueue()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()